# How to show $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} p(1-p)^{k-1} = 1$

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

My textbook claims that it is easy to show that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} p(1-p)^{k-1} = 1$$

I disagree. Yes it is easy to show that the sum converges, but not that it converges to one. Or is there a straighforward way to show that?

Comment: If $S=a+ar=ar^2+\cdots+ar^{n-1}$, then $Sr-S=a(r^n-1)$

Comment: How is it easy to prove convergence without any assumption on $p$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's (nearly) a geometric serie :

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty p(1-p)^{k-1} = p \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$ (with $x=1-p$)

So it's equal to

$p \frac{1}{1-x} = p\frac{1}{1-(1-p)} = 1$

Comment: Ops! I totally forgot about geometric sum... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty p(1-p)^{k-1}=p\sum_{k=0}^\infty(1-p)^k=\frac p{1-(1-p)}=1,$$assuming that $p\in(0,2)$.

Answer (score 3):

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (1-p)^{k-1} $ is a geometric series, so if $|1-p|<1$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (1-p)^{k-1}=\frac{1}{1-(1-p)}=\frac{1}{p} $$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} p(1-p)^{k-1} =p\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (1-p)^{k-1}=p\frac{1}{p}=1 $$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** If $S$ is the sum, then $(1-p)S$ is the same sum starting from index $k=2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} p(1-p)^{k-1} =p\sum_{k=1}^{n} (1-p)^{k-1}=1-(1-p)^n$$ So, if $0<p<1$, then ...

Comment: It doesn't have to be $0<p<1$

Answer (score 0):

If the probability of an event $A$ occurring is $p$, it is denoted as $P(A)=p$. We repeat event $A$ until it happens, and we call it event $B$. Apparently $P(B) =1$. Another way to calculate $P(B)$ can also be used. The probability of the first event $A$ occurring is $p$, the probability of the second occurrence is $p(1-p)$, the probability of the third occurrence is $p(1-p)^2$, and so on. In the end, we get a formula $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}p(1-p)^{k-1}$. Since $P(B)$ is the same, we get that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}p(1-p)^{k-1}=1$. That's what we're asking for.